# Sensitive data in Xcode project files?

Tags: xcode, git, app-store

There are a lot of strange files such as pbxproj, xcscheme, xcconfig, etc. Is there any sensitive data that are in Xcode project files that I shouldn't check in?

I've submitted my app to the App Store so I wanted to make sure there wasn't any sensitive info in the project files by default that I should explicitly leave out of public source control (it's an open source project).

Answer (score 2):

None of this will be compiled into the app, it only really matters if you are sharing source code with others. If you use source control like git then you should set up .gitignore to ignore these files.

Here is the github suggested .gitignore file:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore

Comment: It's an open source project so I do want to share the code and allow others to fork/run it. I just want to not share sensitive data.

Comment: See the example .gitignore file, this will ensure no unnecessary files get committed into source control

Answer (score 1):

I am currently in the process of making my app's GitHub repository public, so I wanted to share the steps that I took to safely list my project as public. Firstly, sensitive files are anything that includes identifiers, API keys, passwords, etc. Even usernames may be considered sensitive.

### Background

My app utilizes:

- In-App Purchase (via Apple)
- Google AdMob

### Sensitive Info

In my project, I had various elements that could be considered sensitive:

- `productIdentifier` (In-App Purchase)

  - *A string that identifies a product that can be purchased in your app.*
- `adUnitID` (AdMob AdUnit ID)

  - *...Set this to the ID assigned for this placement. Ad units are important for targeting and statistics.*
- `GADApplicationIdentifier` (same value `adUnitID` holds, inside `Info.plist` )

### Handling Sensitive Info

To handle the sensitive information in my app, I created a file, `Identifiers.swift`, and created an `enum` inside of that file which served my purposes.

```swift
enum Identifiers {
    static let productID: String = // productIdentifier here
    static let adUnitID: String = // adUnitID here
    // other sensitive elements
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure to replace instances of these identifiers and other sensitive information with the declared elements in the enum, like so:

```swift
...paymentRequest.productIdentifier = Identifiers.productID

...GADInterstitial(adUnitID: Identifiers.adUnitID)
```

Also, **do not** forget to remove commented lines that may contain sensitive information. I had my real `adUnitID` commented out due to the fact I was using a test identifier.

I then created a `.gitignore` file from the repo that the link in the other answer belongs to:

- [github / gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore)
- [github / gitignore / Swift.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore)

In `.gitignore`, I added these lines:

```
Source/SupportingFiles/Identifiers.swift
Source/SupportingFiles/Info.plist
APPNAME.xcodeproj
```

I chose to ignore the `Info.plist` for a few reasons:

- When making changes to `Info.plist`, those changes may be easy to forget. If one of these changes includes sensitive information and you forget to ignore the file, this could be an issue.
- In my case, I only want to source files to show up in my GitHub repository - I would prefer if others couldn't download my app and use it "straight-out-of-the-box" (this is up to personal preference)

You will also notice how I chose to ignore the `.xcodeproj` folder. Again, this is completely up to personal preference regarding how you want others to be able to use your project.

### Making Changes Visible in Remote

After committing and pushing the necessary files to your GitHub repo (don't forget to push the `.gitignore`, too), run this command from the root directory of your project:

```sh
git rm -r --cached <file1> <file2>
```

Or, if you want to update entire project at once:

```sh
git rm -r --cached .
```

Then, commit and push the changes to the GitHub repo.